# DATE type comparison in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Had a bit unintuitive case right now with MySQL:
the query contains where clause with comparison: `WHERE t.date = '2016-12-31'` (t.date-s datatype is DATE(!)).. And it returns no records on execution. But the query: `WHERE t.date > '2016-12-31'` - returns the records with `date` equals '2016-12-31' among other records! The record for 2016-12-31 also showed up in case I've used `BETWEEN '20161231' AND '20170101'`. Tried formattings, type changes - nothing helped. After some time spent on searching for cause I did the following: updated the record's `date` column manually, SETting it to '2016-12-31'. After this action `WHERE t.date = '2016-12-31'` started to work as expected.
Probably I'm missing something, wondering what can cause such behavior.
**Update**
date is DATE, not DATETIME
[image]

After doing manual update I can't reproduce the mentioned behavior again: now any type of comparison(=, DATE(..)=, STRCMP) - works as it should!
**Update 2**
For 2016-11-30 and 2016-09-30(end of months!) found the same behavior! Won't update the record manually for now to test the suggestions I get here.
**Update 3**
I've also run OPTIMIZE TABLE on the table with that date column to rebuild indexes for elimination any problems with corruption.
**Update 4**
Here is more:
if I check HEX values for the date field for incorrect fields(end of month) I get wrong values!
`SELECT HEX(t.date) FROM table t WHERE t.date BETWEEN DATE('20160930') AND DATE('20161001');`
Returns:
323031362D31302D3030
323031362D31302D3031
`SELECT HEX(DATE('20160930'));`
Returns:
323031362D30392D3330
And 323031362D30392D3330 != 323031362D31302D3030
`SELECT X'323031362D31302D3030';`
And it returns:
2016-10-00, NOT 2016-09-30!
For the value that I've updated manually - HEX is same.
But what can cause such difference?

Comment: Sure it is not DATETIME?

Comment: Could you format the queries a bit better, ideally as complete code blocks?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the field is of type DATE rather than DATETIME?

Comment: @juergend - Added screenshot from DataGrip with table scheme part.

Comment: Could the problem be the character encoding?

Comment: @CptMisery , but there are only numbers. Can ascii ranged numbers be aware of character encoding?

Comment: I think so. Since your query for that date didn't work until you manually updated a record to that date, I think the code that is inserting records is improperly encoding the data

Comment: @CptMisery I'll recheck this tomorrow, this is still nice version, but the problem is that other records from the same table, done using SAME client code are OK. The mentioned problem was with that single record and now I'm afraid if there are other records like that, because based on such comparisons I'm building important reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation I've found the problem and its not related directly to the date comparison in MySQL. I'll post it here in case anyone is stuck at such case.
I've found that the problem was with selecting results in IDE (in my case [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/)): the value for date field in database was 2016-10-**00**  and select was returning 2016-09-30! That was confusing.. But after the 00 DAY was found - it was relatively easy to find the cause of it: `CURDATE() - 1` (in my case there should have been: `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY`). Don't ever use date related functionality without specific functions like INTERVAL!!
Thanks to everyone who supported the question, sorry for confusion, I was confused too and found the answer only after several steps.

Answer (score 1):

Try forcing the format using

```
WHERE date(t.date)  = '2016-12-31'
```

or

```
WHERE date(t.date)  = str_to_date( '2016-12-31', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

or based on your test

```
WHERE date(t.date)  = str_to_date( '20161231', '%Y%m%d')
```

Comment: UPDATE table SET date = '20161230' WHERE ID = ... and after that - back to 31: UPDATE table SET date = '20161231' WHERE ID = ...

Comment: I have sligthly updated  my answer  please check and let me know

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce it now.. As I've said: after update even = '20161231' works well. By the way, if I'm comparing to DATE datatype do I really need: `WHERE date(t.date)  = str_to_date( '2016-12-31', '%Y-%m-%d')` and not just `WHERE t.date = '2016-12-31'`?

Comment: Based on mysql default date conversion ...could be that a correct evaluation of month and day  need  a proper conversione  .. but just for the string side ...for the column side .. should be already a date ..

Comment: Oh! Thats just nice.. I CAN reproduce all the cases now: for 2016-11-30 THE same is happening with record! For date > '2016-11-30' -shows the record for 2016-11-30, for = '2016-11-30' 0 records found. Tried `date(t.date)  = str_to_date( '20161130', '%Y%m%d')` and 0 records again.

Comment: This is really strange

Comment: And same for 2016-10-31! Seems like end of month problem?!

Comment: and for others date (not month ending)    no problems?

Comment: Comparison with 2016-10-30 - works as it should :( Will recheck the client code that is inserting these records tomorrow; there was suggesting about encoding problem, but I dont think there is encoding issue in DATE column.

Comment: Could be  .. a TIMEZONE ... issue ?

Comment: t.date = '2016-10-01' - works, t.date = '2016-09-30' - no, but again - there IS date = '20160930' in recordset returned by t.date > '2016-09-30'

Comment: Timezone - thats logical.. How can i recheck that? For now we have all the records with GMT+4 timezone set using `SET SESSION time_zone = '+4:00'; `

Comment: Experimented with: `date(t.date+INTERVAL +10 HOUR) = '2016-09-30'` - not working.. As if I'm not comparing dates! :(

Comment: Btw, a simpler & shorter & Standard SQL compliant way to write a date is `DATE '2016-12-31` instead of `str_to_date`.

Comment: @dnoeth such conversion didn't work in my case either.